# MongoDB query between date range

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In my mongodb , the date column in string. It holds date time as 8/3/2020 13:50:19.

I am unable to do any date range query. It's returning wrong results.

My code is as follows :

```
{       
                "$match": {                
                           "event.meterID.string": meter_no, 
                           "event.dataTime.string": {
                                      "$gte": prev,
                                      "$lte": dt_string
                            } 
                        } 
               }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f2707da47973204ce5e9d91"), "header" : { "endpointKeyHash" : { "string" : "mO5KmJVhbZMXAUrVD0uKIKf32/I=" }, "applicationToken" : { "string" : "96775772132708234336" }, "headerVersion" : { "int" : 1 }, "timestamp" : { "long" : NumberLong("1596393434007") }, "logSchemaVersion" : { "int" : 4 } }, "event" : { "meterID" : { "string" : "83.67.68.65.48.48.49.49" }, "rkw" : { "double" : -4492 }, "rkwh" : { "double" : 2 }, "rkvar" : { "double" : -2331 }, "rkv" : { "double" : 6499574 }, "rcurrent" : { "double" : 29367 }, "rhz" : { "double" : 50021 }, "rpf" : { "double" : 650 }, "ykw" : { "double" : 0 }, "ykwh" : { "double" : 0 }, "ykvar" : { "double" : 0 }, "ykv" : { "double" : 6524626 }, "ycurrent" : { "double" : 15370 }, "yhz" : { "double" : 0 }, "ypf" : { "double" : 0 }, "bkw" : { "double" : 0 }, "bkwh" : { "double" : 0 }, "bkvar" : { "double" : 0 }, "bkv" : { "double" : 6616274 }, "bcurrent" : { "double" : 34841 }, "bhz" : { "double" : 0 }, "bpf" : { "double" : 0 }, "dataTime" : { "string" : "8/3/2020 00:04:43" } } }
```

Comment: Show us some documents

Comment: **NEVER** store date/time values as strings, use proper `Date` objects.

Comment: I have share the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, the problem is that the date is stored as a string and not a proper `datetime` datatype. On string fields, when you use the `$lte` and `$gte` operators, MongoDB will compare the values as strings (lexicographic order), not as dates.

Aside from converting the stored dates to `datetime`, there are a couple more options:

1. Store the dates in a lexicographically orderable string format, such as ISO 8601. If the date is represented as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`, it can be compared as a string as well.
2. Create an aggregation that converts the strings to a date object before comparing them. This is not efficient for queries because it will need to convert all dates in all documents before applying the filter and therefore does not use any indexes, however you can do:

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "eventDateTime": {
      "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": "$event.dataTime.string",
        format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$match": {
    "event.meterID.string": meter_no,
    "eventDateTime": {
      "$gte": prev,
      "$lte": date_object
    }
  }
}
```

It is generally recommended to store dates as `datetime` fields, this way you have not only support for comparisons, but also timezone conversions, filtering on subfields of the date (such as, for example, finding all documents for a specific day or month), etc.

Corrected the date switches. Otherwise, the answer is correct.